# Natural deduction: premise with simultaneous negated universal and existential quantifiers

Tags: first-order-logic, natural-deduction

I need to prove this natural deduction theorem:

$\neg \exists x.\neg \forall y.S_{1}^{1}(x) \implies S_{2}^{1}(y) \lor S_{3}^{1}(y)$,
$S_{1}^{1}(c_1)$,
$\neg S_{2}^{1}(c_2)$
$\vdash_{N} \exists z. S_{3}^{1}(z)$.

I understand how natural deduction works. However, I'm having some trouble understanding how to handle the quantifier's negations. I'm not sure if I should use equivalence rules (I mean, is that valid in natural deduction?) for the quantifiers to get rid of them.

Can you help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The basic ND rules do not include the equiv of $\lnot \exists \lnot$ with $\forall$

Comment: With the basic rules, you can start with the assumption $\lnot \exists z S_3 (z)$ and derive a contradiction, concluding with DN.

Comment: Can you try from this hint, showing your efforts, please?